# how to insert any twitter user profile link while composing a tweet

Tags: twitter, tweets, rtweet

I try to search a lot but did not get any solution, please help me with this.
how do i insert any twitter user profile link while composing a tweet, its almost like mentioning someone but it shows a twitter user avatar & name just like in this tweet https://twitter.com/DepressedDarth/status/924689808265482240?[screenshot from a tweet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysNUz.jpg)

Comment: Amir, I am sure this does not have any thing to with programming. 
This is a programming Q/A site. please delete your question or the community will make you delete it. :)
TIA.

Comment: sorry for that where should i add my question

Comment: you can try that on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/) or [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the API to look at the status, using `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show/924689808265482240.json` this is what you'll see

```
"text": "This is what I do for fun now https:\/\/t.co\/VNEAbw4YRC",
```

The user has sent a Tweet containing a link. Where does t.co/VNEAbw4YRC point to?

https://twitter.com/DepressedDarth/status/879169042426318848/video/1

So, here's what the user has done.

1. Post a video to Twitter - in this case, in June 2017.
2. Wait several months.
3. Copy the video URL of the Tweet - add `/video/1` to it.
4. Post a new Tweet and include the video URL of the old Tweet.

Twitter will then render the Tweet with a link back to the original user who posted the video.  I think they do this to prevent people just linking to a different user's video and then claiming it for themselves.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what i was looking for, i really appreciate your help.